# SMTP Client gives the errror 'Instance names used for writing to custom counters must be 127 characters or less'

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtpclient

I'm getting a strange error trying to send an email a c# .NET 3.5 winforms application. When I start a new SMTPClient like this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred
>    Message=Instance names used for writing to custom counters must be 127 characters or less. 
>    Source=System
>    StackTrace:
>          at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter..ctor(String catName, String counterName, String instanceName, PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime lifetime)
>    InnerException:

I get the same line no matter how I start the new SMTPClient, e.g.

`SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);`

I read that this might have to do with a long directory structure but I can't change that. I also read it might be to do with unit testing, but I'm not doing any kind of unit testing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message refers to the Peformance Counter, which I assume is being called from inside the "new SmtpClient" call. It's complaining about the length of the "instance name" parameter.

Have you tried moving the executing code closer to the drive root? (ex. execute it from c:\temp or similar).